# How to show edit and then final version of a form to the user in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Currently I have a codeigniter form, where the user fills a subject, a message text area, two static uploads, a third dynamic upload (that depends on a particular value from a 3rd select), an email destiny select, an email sender select, a text input for a start service date (a jquery datepicker resulted in a nightmare!), an observations text area, a preview email button, a "Correct Contents" button (currently pending), and a logout button, the purpose of the preview email button is to upload the contents and data to a DB and to send an email to the user's own email address in order to preview what he/she will be sending (the contents in the form) to the recipients, if everything is Ok, then he/she will click on the "Correct Contents" button, otherwise, the user should be able to edit the contents on the form, preferably on the same view, with the same contents and the 3rd (if any) jquery-ajax upload.

Am working on the email thing, where I have problem is how to upload the contents to the DB and reloading the very same view with the very same contents, to give the user the chance to edit them or to final post them in order to be processed.

Formerly I just had an Upload button where after uploading contents the user was redirected using a:

```
$this->forma_model->set_records();
$this->load->view('news/success');
```

but now I´ve been required to preview the content, and then a "Correct Contents" button if nothing to edit, then that would send me to the success view, as before. Thanks i.a.

Comment: So what exactly is the question? What problem are you having? Are you getting errors?

Comment: The problem is what should I do to post the form data?, including that from the dynamic select, without losing the view of the form, keeping all in its place (including the dynamic select), given that it´s a preview of the data to be posted, the subsequent step would be to post the data (in final version) to be processed and moving to the next view, thanx i.a.

Comment: Solved it making that 3rd upload static, as the DB accepts NULL for its value is not that important the dynamic side, it was nicer but turned complex to reload that part, so after uploading I sent the to a view with a warning, if nothing is wrong then a "Finish" process button is there to... finish the process, if something needs to be changed, then a click on a -simple js- "Go back" button takes the user to the previous page, keeping the same session id, forming a loop that ends when the user clicks on the "Finish" button.